# Single Sign On connection from ASP.NET webforms with Kentor authservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, pingfederate, kentor-authservices

I’ve recently started using the Kentor open source packages to do a SSO connection to a PingFederate service from a ASP.NET Webforms application.

Everything seemed to work when I tested with the test service Kentor provided. However when I connected to PingFederate the people managing the service reported that my request was empty. Upon investigation we discovered that we needed to send login or login and password in the SAML request. Can this be done with the packages you provided?

Comment: Are you the IdP or SP? If you're the IdP, then you should be sending a SAML Response, otherwise you should be sending an AuthnRequest.

Comment: @AndrewK. He's the SP. Does Ping federate have any specific requirements on the AuthnRequest?

Comment: Indeed, I am the SP. The people managing the Ping Federate require that I already send the login of the user in the AuthRequest

Answer (score 1):

Within PingFederate for SAML 2.0, there is no specific requirement to provide user or password, though you can pass the user as `<saml:Subject>`. Any spec-compliant "simple" signed `AuthnRequest` that merely provides a relay state, ACS URL, and EntityID of the SP will do. If your partner is running PingFederate, and they are telling you that they need the user's ID, then they are wrong, unless they are doing something very strange (which has been known to happen).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the `AuthnRequest` to contain a `<saml:Subject>` element with the name of the user you want to authenticate?

That's part of the SAML standard, but unfortunately not supported by Kentor.AuthServices (as of version 0.13.0)